# RXJS in Angular 6 returns only { "_isScalar": false }

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngxs

I'm trying `RXJS` for the first time. Although I'm following the steps I found in a tutorial literally my component isn't getting the sate in the `Store` but instead it's getting the object `{ "_isScalar": false }`.

Here the code:

Component HTML:

```
<div>
    {{ selectedProcess }}
</div>
```

Component TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { Store, Select } from '@ngxs/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Process } from '../../../../models/process';
import { ProcessState } from '../../../../state/process.state';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-process',
  templateUrl: './process.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./process.component.scss']
})
export class OneProcessComponent implements OnInit {
  @Select(ProcessState.getProcess) selectedProcess: Observable<Process>;

  constructor(private store: Store) { }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

PS: I checked the state file and realized the state is updating correctly. Still the receiving component can't get the data but getting the above-mentioned object instead.

Comment: _Where_ are you getting the error? You've included a lot of code without no specific pointer to what is going on.

Comment: @DanielB I don't get an error per say. Just the value of the variable isn't wnat's in the State. But Martin got me the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its observable. You cannot just print it like `{{selectedProcess}}`. You have to use `async` pipe which subscribes to observable and prints out the result:

```
{{selectedProcess | async}}
```

Comment: Oh simple! Thank you!